# Assigning a value without declaring it first?

Tags: javascript, variables, alert, prompt

Can anyone please explain why we CAN assign a value without declaring it first. To my understanding we would need to declare a variable first (var visitorsName = prompt("Input your name: "). What is a visitorName if not variable? Thank you so much!

```
 visitor_name = prompt("Input your name : ");
 if(visitor_name !=null && visitor_name != ""){
   alert("Your name is: " + visitor_name);
 } else {
   alert("No Name User")
 }
```

Comment: For kicks, you can turn off this behavior by using strict mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When javascript was created, it was expected to be used for small scripts and often by novice programmers. As a result, it was designed to tolerate some sloppy coding practices. One of the ways it does this is that if you fail to declare your variable, it will create a global variable for you.

When this line runs:

```
 visitor_name = prompt("Input your name : ");
```

Javascript will create a property on the `window` object named `visitor_name`. And later on, any time you refer to visitor_name, since there's no other variable with that name, it will access `window.visitor_name`

I recommend you avoid using this "feature" of javascript, and just declare your variables explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are loosely typed, which means you can assign any type of value to a variable.

Scope of the variables declared without var keyword become global irrespective of where it is declared. Global variables can be accessed from anywhere in the web page

```
x = 1;
console.log(x);
x = "one";
console.log(x);
```

However it is not recommended to declare a variable without it's data type because it messes with the scope of other variables and may change the value of some global variable.